# OpenCV for iOS build errors

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, opencv

I'm trying to import the files from [this github project](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVStitch) to enable image stiching for

my app. I downloaded the project, and ran it on my phone and it worked great. However,

after adding it's files into my XCode project, I get these two errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat> > const&)", referenced from:


Unable to open executable '...'
```

Originally I had 40+ errors which I solved by doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14864321).

```
I've modified my new XCode project to reflect the OpenCV github project. Thoughts?
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you've included OpenCV framewrok correctly into your Xcode project.

[Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/2.4.4/opencv2.framework.zip/download) to download latest opencv framework source code .

Just include this folder as a framework into your project.