# Compiling Qt and OpenCV for arm64-v8a

Tags: android, c++, qt, opencv, arm64

I am trying to compile a program using Qt and OpenCV for arm64-v8a
I created a kit to use an arm64-v8a version of Qt, but I get tons of undefined reference errors

I have compiled Qt using the following parameters :

```
./configure -xplatform android-clang \
 --disable-rpath -nomake tests -nomake examples \
 -android-ndk <ndk-r16b-root> -android-sdk <sdk-root> -android-ndk-host linux-x86_64 \
 -android-toolchain-version 4.9 -android-ndk-platform android-21 -android-arch arm64-v8a \
 -skip qttranslations -skip qtserialport -skip qtwebengine -no-warnings-are-errors \
 -prefix <install-dir> -opensource -confirm-license
```

Then I added 2 compilers, the first for C and the second for C++ :

```
<ndk-r16b-root>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
```

with ABI : <custom> arm-linux-android-elf-64-bit

```
<ndk-r16b-root>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++
```

with ABI : <custom> arm-linux-android-elf-64-bit

I cloned the auto-detected kit for this version of Qt and used the following settings :

```
Device type : Android Device
Device : Run on Android (default for Android)
Sysroot : <ndk-r16b-root>/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64
Compilers : the 2 above
Android GDB server : <ndk-r16b-root>/prebuilt/android-arm64/gdbserver/gdbserver
Qt version : the one I just compiled
Qt mkspec : android-clang
```

Other fields are left empty/by default

My .pro file looks like this :

```
QT += quick multimedia multimediawidgets
CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

HEADERS += <my-headers>
SOURCES += <my-sources>

RESOURCES += qml/qml.qrc

INCLUDEPATH += OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include

LIBS += -L"OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/arm64-v8a"\
        -L"OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/arm64-v8a"\
        -llibtiff\
        -llibjpeg\
        -llibjasper\
        -llibpng\
        -lIlmImf\
        -llibwebp\
        -lopencv_core\
        -ltbb\
        -lopencv_flann\
        -lopencv_imgproc\
        -lopencv_highgui\
        -lopencv_features2d\
        -lopencv_calib3d\
        -lopencv_ml\
        -lopencv_objdetect\
        -lopencv_video\
        -lopencv_photo\
        -lopencv_videostab\
        -ltegra_hal\
        -lopencv_imgcodecs\
        -lopencv_shape\
        -lopencv_stitching\
        -lopencv_superres\
        -lopencv_videoio

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar \
    android/gradlew \
    android/res/values/libs.xml \
    android/build.gradle \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties \
    android/gradlew.bat

ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
```

The OpenCV-android-sdk folder comes from [here](https://opencv.org/releases.html) using 3.2.0 Android pack.

When I try to compile, I get tons of undefined references like the followings :

```
OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `cv::SparseMat::newNode(int const*, unsigned long)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9SparseMat7newNodeEPKim+0x4b8): undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<cv::Mat*, std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat> > >, unsigned long, cv::Mat const&)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIN2cv3MatESaIS1_EE14_M_fill_insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EEmRKS1_[_ZNSt6vectorIN2cv3MatESaIS1_EE14_M_fill_insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EEmRKS1_]+0xcd4): undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `std::vector<cv::UMat, std::allocator<cv::UMat> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<cv::UMat*, std::vector<cv::UMat, std::allocator<cv::UMat> > >, unsigned long, cv::UMat const&)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIN2cv4UMatESaIS1_EE14_M_fill_insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EEmRKS1_[_ZNSt6vectorIN2cv4UMatESaIS1_EE14_M_fill_insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EEmRKS1_]+0xbb0): undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
```

The actual linker command used (where errors happen) is :

```
<ndk-r16b-root>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -D__ANDROID_API__=26 -target aarch64-none-linux-android -gcc-toolchain <ndk-r16b-root>/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a --sysroot=<ndk-r16b-root>/platforms/android-26/arch-arm64/ -Wl,-soname,libTest.so -Wl,-rpath-link=<newly-compiled-Qt-root>/lib -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o libTest.so myfilter.o qml_main_qml.o qmlcache_loader.o   -L<ndk-r16b-root>/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a -LOpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs/arm64-v8a -LOpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/arm64-v8a -llibtiff -llibjpeg -llibjasper -llibpng -lIlmImf -llibwebp -lopencv_core -ltbb -lopencv_flann -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_videostab -ltegra_hal -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videoio -L<newly-compiled-Qt-root>/lib -lQt5Quick -lQt5MultimediaWidgets -lQt5Multimedia -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lc++ -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc
```

Edit: tried to compile OpenCV myself, does not work better.
Edit2: I just saw [Petesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17833/petesh)'s answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12920944/9987834
Could this be because my version of Qt and OpenCV have been compiled using different standard libraries?
Edit3: Cannot manage to compile OpenCV correctly, I get errors like this one:

```
skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a when searching for -lopencv_core
```

Edit4: For some reason, OpenCV stopped compiling at all, giving me errors like these:

```
In file included from /path/to/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/algorithm.cpp:43:
In file included from /path/to/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/precomp.hpp:84:
In file included from /path/to/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/intrin.hpp:297:
/path/to/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/intrin_neon.hpp:285:49: error: expected
      unqualified-id
template <typename T> static inline float16x4_t vld1_f16(const T* ptr)
                                                ^
<ndk-r16b-root>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/5.0.300080/include/arm_neon.h:7745:24: note:
      expanded from macro 'vld1_f16'
#define vld1_f16(__p0) __extension__ ({ \
                       ^
[ 31%] Built target libwebp
[ 31%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/command_line_parser.cpp.o
In file included from /path/to/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/algorithm.cpp:43:
In file included from /path/to/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/precomp.hpp:84:
In file included from /path/to/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/intrin.hpp:297:
/path/to/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/intrin_neon.hpp:778:8: error: unknown type
      name 'v_float16x4'; did you mean 'v_float32x4'?
inline v_float16x4 v_load_f16(const short* ptr)
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
       v_float32x4
```

My cake (gui) output is here : https://pastebin.com/ZBrtizUi

Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is a late reply, my comment might help another user updating a deprecated Android project...

Here is my typed CMake command (configured variables are detailled in the linked logfiles):
`cmake ${OPENCV_CMAKEFILE} -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_FILE} -DANDROID_NDK=${ANDROID_NDK_PATH} -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-25 -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF -DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=ON -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=ON-DANDROID_STL=c++_static -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${OPENCV_INSTALL_PATH} -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

1. **With your settings, when FP16 support is enabled using OpenCV 4.5.3**, CMake logs indicates that:

- the test 'HAVE_CPU_NEON_SUPPORT' is performed and validated (executing the check file 'cmake/checks/cpu_neon.cpp')
- the test 'HAVE_CPU_FP16_SUPPORT' is performed and validated (executing the check file 'cmake/checks/cpu_fp16.cpp')
- and the resulting identified CPU/HW features baseline is identified as "NEON FP16" (see [the linked logfile](https://pastebin.com/SpwJXKQ1)).

Finally, **the libraries and example applications are successfully built.**

2. **With your settings, when FP16 support is enabled using OpenCV 3.2.0**, CMake logs indicates that:

- the test 'CXX_HAS_MFPU_NEON' is performed and validated
- the test 'C_HAS_MFPU_NEON' is performed and validated
- the check file 'cmake/checks/fp16.cpp' is ignored.

Finally, **the libraries and example applications are not successfully built** (with the same errors you described). I linked typed commands and both [CMake configuration logs](https://pastebin.com/bTqZkjTc) and [compilation error logs](https://pastebin.com/ucfYPfEs).
**I finally disabled FP16 support and rebuilt OpenCV 3.2.0 successfully. [Prebuilts are accessible here](https://github.com/maximaging/opencv-3.2.0-android-prebuilts).**

From my investigation, it appears that some progress on FP16 compiler support for OpenCV has been integrated (reviewed and merged) following the release 3.2.0. [This merge](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/20321) from June 21 is the latest work on this matter, a comment from @alalek introduces some previous pull requests.